# must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: angular, typescript

I am encountering this error:

```
error TS2488: Type 'Usuario' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method
that returns an iterator.
```

My code:

`usuarios.reducers.ts`

```
export interface UsuarioState {
    users: Usuario[];
    loaded: boolean;
    loading: boolean;
    error: any;
}

const initState: UsuarioState = {
    users: [],
    loaded: false,
    loading: false,
    error: null
}

export function usuariosReducer(state = initState, action: fromUsuariosActions.usuariosAcciones): UsuarioState {

    switch (action.type) {

        case fromUsuariosActions.CARGAR_USUARIOS: 
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }

        case fromUsuariosActions.CARGAR_USUARIOS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                loaded: true,
                users:[...action.usuarios]
            }
```

Screenshot: [image]

I've added `"es5", "dom.iterable"` in my `tsconfig.json` file and still not working, Can you explain to me what's wrong?

`usuarios.actions.ts`

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Usuario } from '../../models/usuario.model';

export const CARGAR_USUARIOS = 'CARGAR_USUARIO'
export const CARGAR_USUARIOS_FAIL = 'CARGAR_USUARIO_FAIL'
export const CARGAR_USUARIOS_SUCCESS = 'CARGAR_USUARIO_SUCCESS'

export class CargarUsuarios implements Action {
    readonly type = CARGAR_USUARIOS;
}

export class CargarUsuariosFail implements Action {
    readonly type = CARGAR_USUARIOS_FAIL;

    constructor(public payload: any) {}
}

export class CargarUsuariosSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = CARGAR_USUARIOS_SUCCESS;

    constructor(public usuarios: Usuario) {}
}

export type usuariosAcciones = CargarUsuarios |
                               CargarUsuariosFail |
                               CargarUsuariosSuccess
```

`usuario.model.ts`

```
export class Usuario {
    constructor(
        public id: number, 
        public first_name: string, 
        public last: string,
        public avatar: string,
    ) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the type definition for `usuariosAcciones`? Looks like `action.usuarios` is not guaranteed to be an array.

Comment: Type definition for usuariosAcciones is:                                                         
 export type usuariosAcciones = CargarUsuarios |
                               CargarUsuariosFail |
                               CargarUsuariosSuccess

Comment: Please share `fromUsuariosActions.usuariosAcciones` definition.

Comment: And how does your `Usuario` model look like?

Comment: export class Usuario {
    constructor(public id: number, 
                public first_name: string, 
                public last: string,
                public avatar: string, ){

    }
}

Comment: So, `Usuario` is a class. And `action.usuarios` points to its instance (which will be an object). We cannot spread `object` into an `array`.

Comment: What you can instead do is `{ ...action.usuarios }` or if you want multiple users, you can do that in an array like so: `[ { ...action.usuarios } ]`.

Comment: If I do {  ...action.usuarios }  I have another error:                                                  Type '{ id: number; first_name: string; last: string; avatar: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Usuario[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more.ts (2740) .   The expected type comes from property 'users' which is declared here on type 'UsuarioState'

Comment: Yea.. Try `[ { ...action.usuarios } ]`. That error occurs because the `users` property is expecting an array of `Usuario`.

Comment: [ { ...action.usuarios } ] worked!, Thank you Vighnesh

Comment: Awesome. I will convert it to an answer. Please also add definition of the `Usuario` model to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `action.usuario` is an `Object` and spreading an object into an `Array` is not defined in the specification of the `spread` operator. Also, the `users` property is expecting an array of `Usuario` objects. So, first, you need to `spread` the object into another `object` and then, add it as an element to the array.

```js
...
    case fromUsuariosActions.CARGAR_USUARIOS_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            loaded: true,
            users:[{...action.usuarios}]
        }
...
```